# PC won't recognize TV as an additional display

Tags: dvi, amd-radeon, hdtv

I'm working with an ATI Radeon HD2400, using a DVI-HDMI cable to connect my PC with my TV.  After being connected for some time, my PC stopped recognising my TV with the error:

```
 Another display not detected.
```

I'm using Win7 and a DVI-HDMI cable (PC to TV). I am using Catalyst 11.11.

When I disconnected my DVI cable and left my VGA connection, it functioned very well, but still gave the error:

```
Another display not detected...
```

Answer (score 1):

Best answer I can come up with... (sorry not the best)

You are not alone...

[Windows support Web Site - Similar problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/another-display-not-detected-win7-64-bit/98fc0c38-1a2f-4580-b2da-f11ae9ba7023)

Lots of people with the same kind of issue... but no real answer...

Check the link in the discussion MAYBE there is actually something special to do that is written in the document... Didn't take time to read as I can't make any tests...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your port for the HDMI has gone dead.  I would actually back up and set the system up on ONLY the HDMI port and that TV and see if it displays as the ONLY monitor vs an additional one.  If that does not work, I'd say you have your answer.

Comment: My tv port is ok !
i tried with another pc * 

i dont know if i reinstall my windows would work... what you think about...

But if has gone...i think i will have to buy new one *...

But before i buy or do something..you think if i reinstall will work again...in your opinion ?